# How to use Unity Application Block Resolve() function in XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, unity-container, instantiation

In my application, when the user first opens it, I register all my viewmodels with the Unity Application Block as singletons. I can later call the Resolve() function to get those instances back in the code behind of my application (in the .cs files).

I would like to be able to use that function in the .xaml files as well. Is this possible? For example, is there an equivalent to this code behind code:

```
myView.DataContext = unityContainer.Resolve<SomeViewModel>();
```

For the .xaml file? For exampe, something like this perhaps?:

```
<Window
...
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SomeApp.ViewModels">

<Window.DataContext>
    <Unity:Resolve vm:SomeViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) for WPF.  The [MVVM implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx) has a [ViewModel Locator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec20) which can be [configured to use Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430866(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec42).

Comment: While this may help, it does not directly answer the question. Is it possible to do something resembling what I have written without using another framework/library?